# RouteCalculation fails with error code 28 (SKRoutingErrorCodeInvalidNumberOfRoutes)

Tags: ios, objective-c, skmaps

I had written the below code for calculating route in offline skmaps. The start and the end coordinates are correct but the route calculation fails with error code (*SKRoutingErrorCodeInvalidNumberOfRoute*). I had also tried setting `route.maximumReturnedRoutes = 3`, but nothing happened.

```
-(void)FindRoute
{
    [SKRoutingService sharedInstance].routingDelegate = self;
    [SKRoutingService sharedInstance].mapView = self.mapView;
    route.startCoordinate = StartCoordinate;
    route.destinationCoordinate = EndCoordinate;
    route.shouldBeRendered = YES;
    route.requestAdvices = YES;
    route.maximumReturnedRoutes = 1;
    route.requestExtendedRoutePointsInfo = NO;
    [[SKRoutingService sharedInstance] calculateRoute:route];
}
```

Comment: Can you also add your start & end coordinates?

Comment: yes, i pass the coordinates from another viewcontroller and inside this findroute: method i tried to print the coordinates in log and the coordinates are correctly printed in the log.

Comment: the setting are ok so there must be something connected with the real values of your start & end coordinate. Can you add your real coordinates to this questions? (the real lat/longs used)